# Irreducible Matrix Cannot be Transformed into Block Upper-Triangular Form

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, neural-networks, network

The well-known title is from:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html

The corresponding digraph is strongly connected or the undirected graph is connected.

However, the following paper (which can be easily downloaded)

`cluster synchronization and isolated desynchronization in complex networks with symmetries`

Please see an example of page 7, where $$B = TAT^{-1},$$ which is shown on p.3 (left column). In this example, $A$ is the **adjacency matrix** (see (8)). As we know, the adjacency matrix of a connected graph is irreducible.

Here, $B$ is diagonal block form matrix, which violates the theorem above. Before carefully understanding the nontrivial procedure to obtain $B$, is there anything wrong in my understanding and argument?

Comment: $T$ is not a permutation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not check the computations of the paper, but $T$ is not a permutation matrix. An irreducible matrix cannot be transformed in a block upper-triangular form by a permutation matrix, but a general base-change can modify the matrix as you want.

An example: any circulant matrix induces a strongly connected graph, but are easily diagonalized by an unitary base-change, and a diagonal is an upper triangular matrix. If $\omega_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then
$$
C_n = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & & \\
 & \ddots & \ddots &\\
 & & \ddots & 1\\
1 & & & 0
\end{pmatrix}\quad 
Q_n = \frac 1 {\sqrt n} (\omega_n^{(i-1)(j-1)})_{i,j}
\implies 
C_n = Q_n  \begin{pmatrix}
1 &  & & \\
 & \omega_n & &\\
 & & \ddots & \\
 & & & \omega_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
 Q_n^H
$$

Comment: Is it possible to explain more about this statement that you wrote "are easily diagonalized by an unitary base-change"' or make a simple example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Amin235 done$ $

Comment: Is your answer is a kind of diagonalization by a discrete Fourier transform? thanks for your edition.

Comment: yes, and it is the base for the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of matrices

Comment: I appreciate you.